# ¿Cómo aplico el bloque try-catch en mi switch?

Tags: java, netbeans, try-catch

Este es mi código para registrar artículos, pero no sé cómo aplicar  el bloque `try- catch` para que cuando me pida ingresar una opcion, y en vez de dato entero le de un dato string y me quite las excepciones.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```
public class ExcepcionArticulos {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<PedidosArticulos> ListaArticulos=new ArrayList<>();
    PedidosArticulos pedidoArticulos=null;
    boolean band= true;
    while (band) {   
        System.out.println("--------------MENU-----------");
        System.out.println("1.- Crear Lista");
        System.out.println("2.- Visualizar Lista Actual");
        System.out.println("3.- Visualizar todas las listas");
        System.out.println("4.- Salir");
        System.out.println("Elige una opcion");

        int v= entrada.nextInt();
        switch(v){ 
            case 1:

               pedidoArticulos = new PedidosArticulos();
                System.out.println("¿Cuantos articulos desea ingresar?");

                     int na = entrada.nextInt();
                      pedidoArticulos.insertarArticulos(na);
                      ListaArticulos.add(pedidoArticulos);       
                break;
            case 2:
                try {
                    pedidoArticulos.visualizarArticulos();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    System.out.println("El objeto pedido esta nulo");
                }

            case 3:
                try {
                    for(PedidosArticulos pA: ListaArticulos) {
                   pA.visualizarArticulos();
                     }
                } catch (NegativeArraySizeException e) {

                }

                break;
                case  4:
                    band=false;
                    break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Opcion Incorrecta");
                        break;


        }            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

algo como esto?

```
 public void callDivide(){
            try {
                int result = divide(2,1);
                System.out.println(result);
            } catch (BadNumberException e) {
                //do something clever with the exception
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println("vrvnfjn");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo aplicaria dentro de un ciclo con el fin de esperar que el usuario si seleccione una opcion valida de tu lista. En mi solucion no ocupo `try` solo utilizo la funcion `entrada.hasNextInt()` para verificar que sea realmente un numero entero lo que el usuario ingresa.

```
int opcion = 0;
boolean opcion_valida = false;
do {
    System.out.println("--------------MENU-----------");
    System.out.println("1.- Crear Lista");
    System.out.println("2.- Visualizar Lista Actual");
    System.out.println("3.- Visualizar todas las listas");
    System.out.println("4.- Salir");
    System.out.println("Elige una opcion");

    if (entrada.hasNextInt()) {
        opcion = entrada.nextInt();
        if (opcion > 0 && opcion < 5){
            opcion_valida = true;
        }else{
            entrada.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Debes seleccionar una opcion valida");
        }
    } else {
        entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Solo debes ingresar numeros");
    }
} while (!opcion_valida);
//Resto de tu codigo
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambiaria tu variable v de int por String.

A partir de Java 7 se permite trabajar switch con cadenas por lo que pondrías como cadena "1"

Ejemplo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<PedidosArticulos> ListaArticulos=new ArrayList<>();
    PedidosArticulos pedidoArticulos=null;
    boolean band= true;
    while (band) {   
        System.out.println("--------------MENU-----------");
        System.out.println("1.- Crear Lista");
        System.out.println("2.- Visualizar Lista Actual");
        System.out.println("3.- Visualizar todas las listas");
        System.out.println("4.- Salir");
        System.out.println("Elige una opcion");

        String v= entrada.nextLine();
        switch(v){ 
            case "1":

               pedidoArticulos = new PedidosArticulos();
               System.out.println("¿Cuantos articulos desea ingresar?");

                 int na = entrada.nextInt();
                  pedidoArticulos.insertarArticulos(na);
                  ListaArticulos.add(pedidoArticulos);       
            break;
        case "2":
            try {
                pedidoArticulos.visualizarArticulos();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println("El objeto pedido esta nulo");
            }

        case "3":
            try {
                for(PedidosArticulos pA: ListaArticulos) {
               pA.visualizarArticulos();
                 }
            } catch (NegativeArraySizeException e) {

            }

            break;
            case  "4":
                band=false;
                break;
           default:
                    System.out.println("Opcion Incorrecta");
                    break;


    }            
    }
```

Comment: Gracias colega, si me ayudó